# List.Exists returns wrong values

Tags: c#

I was using a List to store all the devices retrieved using a third party library. I am using the Exist method  to determine whether a device existing inside a list.

```
bool bDeviceFound = _devicesFound.Exists(delegate(RCDevice device)
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        if (device != null)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"Floor[\d]+\/mycamera[\d]+");
            if (regex.IsMatch(device.FullName))
                retVal = true;
        }
        return retVal;
    });
```

The problem is that delegate never returns true or the execution will never reaches to the code inside the delegate.  Am I doing anything wrong here? I have verified the code inside the delegate and Regular expression returns true whenever a match is found.

device.FullName assumes the value "Floor1/mycamera1" to IsMatch to return true.

As suggested by LasseV.Karlsen in one of the comment below , I tried moving the delegate method into a seperate private static bool method and put a break point there. but execution never hit there. Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of the FullName values of the devices?

Comment: To check if a item is in a list you should use the Contains-Method of the list

Comment: @Tomtom Not if he has to match on properties of the objects, and not the objects themselves.

Comment: @logeeks are you sure the delegate is never running? If you move it out to an external `private static bool` method and set a breakpoint there does it ever get hit? (It *should* work as you wrote it but it may help debugging to extract it to a real method.)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , I tried moving the delegate method into a seperate private static bool method and put a break point there. but execution never hit there. Thanks.

Comment: @logeeks if the delegate isn't getting hit at all are you sure `_devicesFound` isn't empty? Basic question, but I have to ask.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the issue lies in this line:

```
if (regex.IsMatch(rc.FullName))
```

Why are you checking `rc.FullName`? Shouldn't you be checking `device.FullName` instead since `device` is what's defined in the delegate?

As a side note, you ought to move the `Regex` definition outside of the `Exists` call for better performance. Currently it gets recompiled with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Good catch! Must be an external (to the code shown) variable.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, corrected now. still not working. Thank you.

Comment: @logeeks out of curiosity, are you certain the `FullName` value matches your regex pattern's case? To eliminate case-sensitivity doubts you could update your regex and test with the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option. Use this: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"Floor[\d]+\/mycamera[\d]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` - Does that change anything? BTW you don't need to escape the forward slash in the pattern, but that's beside the point.